# Flutter address autofill

Tags: flutter, dart

Need help to create a flutter autofill.
When a user selects his home or office from a dropdown selector the details of address need to autofill the fields down below.

Comment: When I type "flutter autofill" into Google, there seems to be no shortage of tutorials. For me, the third link is a page from the flutter documentation itself. What exactly is your problem with autofill?

Answer (score 1):

onSelected event set the fields controller.text to what u want